# Mail Composer Issue

Tags: iphone, sendmail

Is there a way to get the "from" address of Mail and display it in MFMailComposeViewController?

Is it possible?

Any way to do that..

Please help....

Comment: Be more specific of what you want to do.

Comment: "from" that is specific enough. dsc wants the "from" before the mail form is displayed. I think that is not available in the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fill your MFMailComposeViewController:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// Set up subject
[picker setSubject:mailSubjectString];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:recieverMailAdress]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = bodyString;
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

Edit:

I think you should have an look to [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/)

Comment: I cannot see a single mention of "from" here?!

Comment: The from is automated set if you have configured a mail account on your phone.